# Every conserving metric is Lipschitz equivalent to the euclidean product metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions

**Theorem:** Suppose $n \in \mathbb N$ and for each $i \in \mathbb N, (X_i, \tau_i)$ is a metric space . All conserving metrics on $\Pi_{i=1} ^{n}X_i$ are lipschitz equivalent. In particular, each is lipschitz equivalent to the euclidean product metric $\mu_2$ on $\Pi_{i=1} ^{n} X_i$

> ***Proof.*** Suppose $d$ is a conserving metric on $\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then $d$ and $\mu_2$ are Lipshitz stronger than $\mu_{\infty}$ **and Lipshitz weaker than $\mu_1$**. Moreover, we have $$\mu_{\infty}(a,b)\le\mu_2(a,b)\le\mu_1(a,b)\le n\mu_\infty(a,b),$$
> for all $a,b\in\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, so that $\mu_{\infty}$ and $\mu_1$ are Lipshitz constant.

**Some Background:**

**Conserving metric**: Suppose $(X,d) $ and $(X_i, \tau_i)$ are metric spaces for every      $i$, where $X= \prod_{i=1} ^n X_i.~~~ d~$ is termed as a Conserving metric iff $\max \{\tau_i(a_i,b_i)~|~i \in (1,\cdots ,n)\} \le d(a,b) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i (a_i,b_i)$

- $\mu_1:(a,b)\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\tau_i(a_i,b_i);$
- $\mu_2:(a,b)\mapsto\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\tau_i(a_i,b_i)^2};$
- $\mu_2:(a,b)\mapsto\max\{\tau_i(a_i,b_i):i\in\Bbb N\}$

**Point of Confusion:**

> I understand that $d$ and $\mu_2$ are lipschitz stronger than $\mu_\infty$ as $d(a,b) \le n~\mu_\infty(a,b)$ and $\mu_2 \le n~\mu_\infty(a,b)$. But, I am unable to understand why they are lipschitz weaker than $\mu_1$ particularly when $d(a,b) \le \mu_1(a,b)$ as per definition of conserving metric.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of conserving metric you gave, we have

$$ \mu_\infty(a,b) \leq d(a,b) \leq \mu_1(a,b). $$

As $\mu_1(a,b) \leq n \mu_\infty (a,b)$, we have $\frac{1}{n}\mu_1(a,b) \leq \mu_\infty (a,b)$ and hence

$$\frac{1}{n} \mu_1(a,b) \leq  \mu_\infty (a,b)  \leq d(a,b). $$

Comment: Thanks. But to prove that $d $ is weaker than  $\mu_1$, we would need an in equality: $\mu_1(a,b) \le d(a,b) $, for all $a,b$ in X. How do we have have that relation?

Comment: In the proof, highlighted in bold, they have mentioned that  d is weaker than $μ_1$

Comment: @MathMan I used the fact that Lipschitz equivalence is an equivalence to prove the statement. In case you only want the bound, you just note $\mu_1(a,b)\leq n\mu_\infty (a,b)$ and thus $1/n \mu_1(a,b) \leq \mu_\infty(a,b) \leq d(a,b)$ as $d$ is conserving.

Comment: Okay... Though I still am not able to understand how that means $\mu_1(a,b) \le d(a,b)$. Could you please explain since you showed $1/n \mu_1(a,b) \le d(a,b)$

Comment: Would really appreciate if you could explain a bit how you used Lipschitz equivalence to prove the statement about $\mu_1$

Comment: @MathMan We do NOT have the $\mu_1(a,b) \leq d(a,b)$, otherwise we would have $\mu_1(a,b)=d(a,b).$ Just look at the definition of Lipschitz stronger/weaker.

Comment: @MathMan Could you tell me, which part of my post is unclear to you? Maybe then I could expand on that.

Comment: How's $d$ weaker than $\mu_1$?

Comment: My book says $d_1$ is Lipschitz stronger than$d_2$ when $d_1(a,b) \le k d_2(a,b)$

Comment: @MathMan Is it fine now?